# Convert multiple queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display the below:

```
month no.      1
month          January
total income   $xx
```

all in one 'query'

Currently I'm using the code below to display the output that I want. However, I want to know is it possible to code it in one query to display the desired output?

Current code used:

```
DECLARE @january int = 0
SELECT Month(Transaction_Date) AS Month_Number,
DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, @january, 0)) AS 'Month',
CONCAT('$', SUM(Credit_Amount)) AS Total_Income
FROM Income 
WHERE Transaction_Date 
BETWEEN '2020-01-01' 
AND '2020-01-31'
GROUP BY 
MONTH(Transaction_Date)

DECLARE @february int = 1
SELECT Month(Transaction_Date) AS Month_Number,
DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, @february, 0)) AS 'Month',
CONCAT('$', SUM(Credit_Amount)) AS Total_Income
FROM Income 
WHERE Transaction_Date 
BETWEEN '2020-02-01' 
AND '2020-02-29'
GROUP BY 
MONTH(Transaction_Date)

DECLARE @march int = 2
SELECT Month(Transaction_Date) AS Month_Number,
DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, @march, 0)) AS 'Month',
CONCAT('$', SUM(Credit_Amount)) AS Total_Income
FROM Income 
WHERE Transaction_Date 
BETWEEN '2020-03-01' 
AND '2020-03-31'
GROUP BY 
MONTH(Transaction_Date)

DECLARE @april int = 3
SELECT Month(Transaction_Date) AS Month_Number,
DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, @april, 0)) AS 'Month',
CONCAT('$', SUM(Credit_Amount)) AS Total_Income
FROM Income 
WHERE Transaction_Date 
BETWEEN '2020-04-01' 
AND '2020-04-30'
GROUP BY 
MONTH(Transaction_Date)
```

Comment: Its not OK to ask for urgent help on this site.

Comment: And please only tag a single RDBMS - MySQL <> SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `EOMONTH` which is the last day of the month

```sql
SELECT
    Month(EOMONTH(Transaction_Date)) AS Month_Number,
    DATENAME(MONTH, EOMONTH(Transaction_Date)) AS [Month],
    CONCAT('$', SUM(Credit_Amount)) AS Total_Income
FROM Income 
WHERE Transaction_Date >= '2020-01-01' AND Transaction_Date < '2020-05-01'
GROUP BY 
    EOMONTH(Transaction_Date);
```

Comment: If it works for you then you can upvote (by pressing the up arrow) and/or accept the answer (by pressing the check)